# 4th argument in reduce

Tags: javascript, typescript, reduce

Here is the function:

```
 function chunk(array: number[], size: number): number[][] {
    return array.reduce((chunks, curr, _, arr) => {
        console.log(arr.length); // -> 10 which is correct

        // let len = arr.length; // -> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

        let len = chunks.length; // this works
        if (len === 0 || chunks[len - 1].length === size) chunks.push([curr]);
        else chunks[len - 1].push(curr);
        return chunks;
    }, []);
}

    console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3)); // ->[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ], [ 10 ] ]
```

The fourth argument to `reduce` is the array that we're iterating over. I can log it and I get the correct result (10) see above. But when I try to use it and assign it to a variable I get an error(see above). Could someone please shed some light?

Comment: It's not `arr.length` that's undefined, it's `chunks[(len - 1)].length`, because then `len` isn't the length of `chunks`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Mozilla's page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), the fourth parameter is the array that is being reduced. You should access the `array` variable that is already declared, but the fourth parameter works.

For example:

```js
array.reduce((_, __, ___, arr) => {
  console.log(arr.length == array.length) // true, this is the source array
});
```

The reason why you're getting the error is not because of the `arr.length` property, but rather the way you're accessing chunks.

Comment: _"false, this is the reduced array"_ - no, _true_, because it's the source array. The _first_ parameter is the reduced array (well, it would be if you'd passed an array or `array[0]` was an array). (Or rather: syntax error, because your argument list lacks parentheses and then because you can't have `_` multiple times.)

Comment: The 4th parameter is the array to traverse, i.e. the source array. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters)